# Nginx cache bypass by custom response header

Tags: caching, nginx

I want to implement a custom nginx cache control method from my scripts, by using a custom header: "Do-Cache". 
I used in http block of nginx:

```
map $sent_http_do_cache $nocache {
        public 0;
        default 1;
}
```

And in the server block of nginx:

```
fastcgi_cache_bypass $nocache;
fastcgi_no_cache $nocache;
```

So, for `Do-Cache: public`, nginx should cache the response. Otherwise not.

But this configuration is not working. By debuging into logs the values of `$sent_http_do_cache` and `$nocache` are the right ones, until they are used in server block of nginx. If using them in the server block (`fastcgi_cache_bypass $nocache`, or a simple `set $a $nocache`), the `$nocache` variable got the "1" value, and `$sent_http_do_cache` - "-".

Is the any other way of managing the cache of nginx based on custom header in response?

Answer (score 0):

Caching based on the response header cannot be done because it implies that Nginx must proxy the request back to the backend and check its response, defeating the purpose of the proxy cache.